# NoReverseMatch at /wiki/edit/CSS/

Tags: django

Olá, estou iniciando no django e estou a dois dias tentando resolver este problema. Já tentei de tudo que encontrei de outras pessoas com o mesmo problema e não consigo resolver. O código é esse:
Meu HTML enviando a variável 'title' para a urlpattern edit:

```
{% block body %}
    {{ content|safe }}
    <a href="{% url 'edit' title %}"> Edit</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Minha url.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<str:title>/", views.entry, name="title"),
    path("search/", views.search, name="search"),
    path("newpage/", views.newpage, name="newpage"),
    path("edit/<str:title>/", views.edit, name="edit")
]
```

A função view que ela chama:

```
def edit(request, title):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewEntry(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
            content = form.cleaned_data["textarea"]
            util.save_entry(title, content)
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
                "content": markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(title)), "form": NewSearchForm(), "title": title
            })
    else:      
        form2 = NewEntry(initial={'title': title, 'textarea': markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(title))})
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
                "title": title, "form": NewSearchForm(), "form2": form2
            })
```

Me ajudem, por favor!

Answer (score 0):

tens que por tudo dentro de um form:

```js
{% block body %}
    <form method="post">
      {{ content|safe }}
      <a href="{% url 'edit' title %}"> Edit</a>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

estas a usar o metodo "POST" aqui **if request.method == "POST":**, e se não fizeres post, ele não faz nada

Comment: O método post utiliza outra página html, a edit.html que é renderizada no final do método get. Não funcionou =/

Comment: onde está a view que faz render ao html que contem aquele botao?

Comment: O botão do formulario que envia a request post?

Comment: a view que faz render ao html que postou , o que contem o `content`

Comment: ```
def entry(request, title):
    if util.get_entry(title) == None:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
            "form" : NewSearchForm()
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
            "content": markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(title)), "title": title, "form": NewSearchForm()
        })
```